# Property Injection with Autofac 2.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

How do I enable property injection in Autofac 2.5 so that my public ILogger Log property gets set automagically?

I was using the following method to enable property injection in a MVC3 project with Autofac 2.4

```
public class InjectPropertiesByDefaultModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration (IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Activating += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Context.InjectProperties (e.Instance);
        };
    }
}


builder.RegisterModule<InjectPropertiesByDefaultModule> ();
```

but this no longer seems to work with Autofac 2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use the `PropertiesAutowired` method on a registration to indicate that property injection should be performed.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

To set this for all objects in a particular assembly you can use PropertiesAutowired with Autofacs RegisterAssemblyTypes:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Foo).Assembly)
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: Is there a way to set PropertiesAutowired automatically without having to specify it with every registered object?

Comment: Todd, I could neither find a way to do this. I commented on the documentation; maybe Nicholas answers there: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/PropertyInjection